# Docker Registry v2 Images cannot be removed

Tags: docker, docker-registry

Before, I list the images by the API:

```
   curl docker-registry:5000/v2/_catalog
    {"repositories":
        ["tmp.eium.ems"]
    }
```

Then I find the image digest by:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json" -X GET http://docker-registry:5000/v2/tm
p.eium.ems/manifests/latest
{
   "schemaVersion": 2,
   "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
   "config": {
      "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.container.image.v1+json",
      "size": 7440,
      "digest": "sha256:8e9a0dfac41f87fdb04e2e9ab7bb64750e71ee58701f024e498fdbcf69c2d082"
   },
...
```

Then I delete it with CLI:

```
[root@snap460c04 tmp]# curl -X DELETE docker-registry:5000/v2/tmp.eium.ems/blobs/sha256:8e9a0dfac41f87fdb04e2e9ab7bb64750e71ee58701f024e498fdbcf69c2d082
```

No any errors.
But while I check it, the image is still there:

```
[root@snap460c04 tmp]# curl docker-registry:5000/v2/_catalog
{"repositories":["tmp.eium.ems"]}
```

Cannot anybody help?

I think my deletion did work, because if I execute the delete again, an error is reported:

```
[root@snap460c04 tmp]# curl -X DELETE docker-registry:5000/v2/tmp.eium.ems/manifests/sha256:8e9a0dfac41f87fdb04e2e9ab7bb64750e71ee58701f024e498fdbcf69c2d082
{"errors":[{"code":"MANIFEST_UNKNOWN","message":"manifest unknown"}]}
```

Answer (score 2):

The Docker Registry just removed the manifests, but not the blobs of the image.  There's still work to do in order to properly remove images.  At this moment, the garbage collector [does not collect untagged manifests](https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/1844).

I have implemented a script to remove untagged or specific images from the Registry.

Details at:

https://github.com/ricardobranco777/clean_registry

Comment: The link gives a 404.

Comment: @Schuh Please use the ricardobranco/clean_registry Docker image instead.

https://github.com/ricardobranco777/clean_registry

Answer (score 2):

You may not be using the correct digest for the deletion, or be missing a second one to also delete.
Using `"Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json"` header could (have) return(ed) another digest to be deleted for the full tag removal.

[regclient](https://github.com/regclient/regclient) does the job:

```
regctl tag delete docker-registry:5000/tmp.eium.ems:latest
```

Comment: The command deleted the tag only, the image is still there (or at least its name) !

Answer (score 0):

The [tool](https://github.com/ricardobranco777/clean_registry.sh) provide the capability, and works fine with my verification.

Comment: The link gives a 404.